# Angular JS + IE + Jquery compatibility

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-directive

I wan to know which version of angular JS and Jquery workf fine with IE 10.

currently i am using IE 10  & angularjs 1.0.7 & jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: Try the latest version of angularjs: 1.3.8 - Its compatible with IE 9 and above: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie. jQuery is a crutch. If you can avoid using jQuery, you should. AngularJS ships with jqLite which suits most needs.

Comment: I checked with 1.3.8 facing still issues but its working fine with 1.2.5